# Lottery match exercise

Tags: java

I have been busy with a exercise where I need to compare a winning lottery number(which is generated) with existing lottery numbers in a database table.

I manage to loop through all the numbers in the database and subsequently find matches with the winning set of numbers but am struggling to pinpoint in which set of lottery numbers the match was found.
The numbers were placed individually in each database column.
Here I retrieve the values in each row.

```
ResultSet set = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM numberLotto");
    while(set.next())
    {
                String[]row = new String[7]; 
                row[0] = set.getString(1);                   
                row[1] = set.getString(2);
                row[2] = set.getString(3);
                row[3] = set.getString(4);
                row[4] = set.getString(5);
                row[5] = set.getString(6);
                row[6] = set.getString(7);
                entries.add(row);
            }
String[][]listOfNumbers = entries.toArray(new String[entries.size()][7]);
```

I then loop through listOfNumbers and compare all the values with the values of winningNumber.

```
Object[]winningNumber = lottoDrawString.toArray();   

        for (int i=0; i < listOfNumbers.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j < listOfNumbers[i].length; j++)
            {
                for(int k = 0; k < winningNumber.length; k++)
                {
                    System.out.println(listOfNumbers[i][j]);

                    if(listOfNumbers[i][j].equals(winningNumber[k]))
                    {
                        System.out.println("There is a match " + listOfNumbers[i][j] + " and " + winningNumber[k]);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

How can I retrieve the row where the match(es) were found?

kind regards

Comment: query the db for the row with the winning numbers

Comment: Can't help but quote Linus Torvalds here "If you need more than 3 levels of indentation, you're screwed anyway, and should fix your program." . Ok with what I understand, you are doing a lot of heavy lifting in code, can you create a JOIN query in order to check this?

Comment: I don't understand why your algorithm needs to be so complex.  Once you have the winning numbers, why can't you just iterate all candidates and use the List containsAll method?  This would mean taking the lottoDrawString and converting it into a List<Integer>, which is pretty simple.

Comment: Are you trying to check if a given lottery number contains any digit of the winning number ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just do

```
SELECT * FROM numberLotto WHERE FirstNumber = n1 AND SecondNumber = n2 AND ...
```

For that matter, why not just store the lotto numbers as a seven-digit string in the database?

Comment: The problem I see with that is there can be many possible matches of three. Say I have number 4 7 13 23 27 33 4, 4,7,13 can match the ticket, 13, 23, 27 can match...etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

One idea could be to add the line number as table field, retrieve it, and instead of creating and checking numbers, do it with an object, lets say Loterry.

class Lottery

{
  int line, value;

}

You check value field and if it fits your check, return line. Hope it helps :)

Comment: What makes you think there's only one column? It looks to me like there are at least eight columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish the search without doing much "programming". Write a query to do it for you:

`String query = "SELECT * FROM numberLotto WHERE number = " + winningNumber`

The above assumes that your lottery numbers are stored in a field labeled `"number"`. You may also use `AND` or `OR` clauses to search for multiple matches.